# Save / Bookmark Google Ads Keyword Planner Search

Tags: google-ads, google-keyword-tool

I couldn't find anyway to save Google Keyword Planner search results. Copy pasting the url results in loss of data. I don't like to put filters everytime I use this tool. So what is the way to save a search keyword planner ?

For example, I search "T-Shirt" keyword, and remove some of the results like "Man T-Shirt", "Women's T-Shirt".

I want to save this result table.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to save your keyword planner search results.

I'm sharing only 2 considering the context and scope of this question. Pick the one that is most useful to you.

**#1: Exporting refined results**

Good for distributing manual lists to SEOs, content teams, and research team.

1. Search the keyword > refine your keywords via filters and other available refining options there
2. Export the report by clicking 'Down Arrow' Symbol.

**#2: (Recommended) Use Keyword Planner to Plan Actually:**

Save the refined results as a plan and reuse it. You can share the particular plan with your team by giving them access to view via URL (no loss of refined data)

1. Search the keyword > refine your keywords via filters/refining options
2. Click on the **Selection Checkbox** within Table Header Column for Keywords named as '**Keywords (by relevance)**'
3. Upon selecting that, it gives another option to '**Select All**', click that.
4. In the same action bar for selected items, click on '**Create a Plan**'.
5. The system will create a plan using those filters/refined results and save it for you to use later on.
6. **Access that saved plan** by clicking on 'Keyword Planner' tool option from Tools in the top bar. It'll now show you recently saved plan. **Don't forget to rename** it like T-Shirts plan to remember it easily.

---

**Additional tips:**

- **Sharing, Downloading, & Removing the Saved Plan:** When you open that plan, in the top-left (desktop-view) you'll see 4 options. Share plan, download to CSV/excel, remove plan, or create a campaign from the plan. From the share option, enable 'Only you can edit the plan', this will enable the URL to share this particular plan. Use that URL to share across team for discussion or planning or as needed. Otherwise, you can always access your saved plans from Tools > Keyword Planner > Saved Plans.
- You can also add keywords from other searches to this plan. Like search other keyword > from search results select some keywords > add to plan.

Comment: Sorry your 2 options won't help me, because my aim is to look for trends. Both of your recommendations are for only capturing the current time. But I am looking for new added keywords. And at the moment each time I have to re apply filters which causes a lot of time to me. For example I need to look for "t-shirts", but new keywords.

Comment: You asked to 'Save' the 'Results' with 'Used/Applied Filters'. If you want a 'dynamic' reporting with 'saved filters', this is another context. The current answer is still valid  under the given context.